# Properties.Settings.Default.Variable does not exists in current Context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, properties, application-settings

I have gone through various question regarding `Properties.Settings.Default.<My Settings Name>` in stackoverflow and google, but none of them resolved my issue.  
I want check whether my application is running for the first time or not, If first time then load particular form, else skip it.

I have a piece of code in My MDIParent Form load

```
bool isFirstRun = Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRun;
MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRun.ToString());
if (isFirstRun){
    OrganizationDetailsFrm childForm = new OrganizationDetailsFrm();
    childForm.MdiParent = this;
    childForm.Show();

     Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRun = false;
     Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
 }
```

I checked and found that, every time isFirstRun value is false. When I checked in debug mode, I tried to add `Properties.Settings.Default.<My Settings Name>` in  Add Watch, It show The name 'IsFirstRun' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: What is the default value of `IsFirstRun` property? Is that true?

Comment: Default value of IsFirstRun is true

Comment: Can't able to reproduce :( works fine for me.

Comment: I have checked the namespace, Access Modifier of the settings, everything, but I am getting the same problem

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: An alternative approach which I use is to determine if this is the first run after installation of the program (or after switch to a different user logon) is to test if the default document that the program uses has been created yet or not. If not, then I create an empty default document and do any other first-time-only processing. The program stores the user's documents in a folder that is dependent on this: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem in my project.

**Possible Reasons:**

1. You may have multiple 'setting' files in your project.
2. Name space problem can also be the problem (I was unable to figured it out what is exactly is)

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Backup your project first.
2. Delete your existing settings file.
3. Make a new settings file in the project.
4. Drag that new settings file into the Properties Folder (Remember don't do this from Visual Studio, do it from project directory). Now it should work.

Thanks,
Muhammad Fuzail Zubari